# WSO2 ESB Service Integration

Tags: wso2, esb

In Service integration sample, output is coming as 

   
      805 Oakley Seaver Drive
      28.7
      Clermont,  FL
      Clermont CBOC
      352-536-8200 Or 877-469-9037

and which is not a response according ot the proxy service wsdl but it is the response from "getHCCenterInfo" which is third call in proxy service,How can i map this output to actual proxy service output in OUT sequence.

2nd question is what if I want all the center record in one output.. here it is giving one center although after aggregating we have 5 record ... I want it in one output with multiple record...

Please help me to achieve the desire output,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Din't find anything for "outSequence" in the product document... plz help or any link for outSequence.

Comment: what is the sample number? are you referring wso2 documentation?

Comment: I am referring this link in wso2 http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/11/enterprise-service-integration-wso2-esb/